# Parse UTF8 string from ReadOnlySequence<byte>

Tags: c#, .net

How can I parse a UTF8 string from a ReadOnlySequence

ReadOnlySequence is made of parts, and seeing as UTF8 characters are variable length the break in the parts could be in the middle of a character .
So simply using Encoding.UTF8.GetString() on the parts and combining them in a StringBuilder will not work.

Is it possible to parse a UTF8 string from a ReadOnlySequence without first combining them into an array. I would prefer to avoid a memory allocation here.

Comment: Have you tried Utf8Parser  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.utf8parser?view=netstandard-2.1

Comment: Oh yes, I hear you. I guess one option is renting a shared array from the arraypool, copy the sequence into that and then converting it. At least you won't allocate for the array.

Comment: Can you just: `var originalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString([ReadOnlySequence].ToArray());` or, for `C# < 7.2`, `var seq = [ReadOnlySequence].GetPosition(0); var sOK = [ReadOnlySequence].TryGet(ref seq, out ReadOnlyMemory<byte> bytes); string originalString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());`.

Comment: @jimi Absolutely you can use the ToArray(), if you want to allocate a huge array. I can't take the performance hit of doing this. The whole point of ReadOnlySequence is to avoid memory allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with a `Decoder`. It would be something along the lines of this:

```
var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var processed = 0L;
var total = bytes.Length;
foreach (var i in bytes)
{
    processed += i.Length;
    var isLast = processed == total;
    var span = i.Span;
    var charCount = decoder.GetCharCount(span, isLast);
    Span<char> buffer = stackalloc char[charCount];
    decoder.GetChars(span, buffer, isLast);
    sb.Append(buffer);
}
```

From [the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getdecoder?view=netcore-3.0)

> The Decoder.GetChars method converts sequential blocks of bytes into sequential blocks of characters, in a manner similar to the GetChars method of this class. However, a Decoder maintains state information between calls so it correctly decodes byte sequences that span blocks. The Decoder also preserves trailing bytes at the end of data blocks and uses the trailing bytes in the next decoding operation. Therefore, GetDecoder and GetEncoder are useful for network transmission and file operations, because those operations often deal with blocks of data instead of a complete data stream.

Of course the `StringBuilder` would introduce a new source for allocations, but  you can replace it with some other kind of buffer if that is a problem.

Comment: This is a really really bad implementation, frankly; it stackallocs (a) unbounded sizes, (b) in a loop - either of (a) or (b) would be enough to raise a red flag - and it allocates lots of unnecessary intermediate arrays, with lots of extra copies (between the array and whatever `StringBuilder` chooses to do internally)

Answer (score 10):

It seems that .NET 5.0 introduced [`EncodingExtensions.GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodingextensions.getstring?view=net-5.0) to solve this problem.

> Decodes the specified ReadOnlySequence into a String using the specified Encoding.

```
using System.Text;

string message = EncodingExtensions.GetString(Encoding.UTF8, buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful find! It's extension though, so call it like any kind of extension:

```string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);```

Answer (score 6):

The first thing we should do here is test whether the sequence actually is a single span; if it is, we can *hugely* simplify and optimize.

Once we know that we have a multi-segment (discontiguous) buffer, there are two ways we can go:

1. linearize the segments into a contiguous buffer, probably leasing an oversized buffer from ArrayPool.Shared, and use UTF8.GetString on the correct portion of the leased buffer, or
2. use the `GetDecoder()` API on the encoding, and use that to populate a new string, which on older frameworks means overwriting a newly allocated string, or in newer frameworks means using the `string.Create` API

The first option is *massively simpler*, but involves a few memory-copy operations (but no additional allocations other than the string):

```cs
public static string GetString(in this ReadOnlySequence<byte> payload,
    Encoding encoding = null)
{
    encoding ??= Encoding.UTF8;
    return payload.IsSingleSegment ? encoding.GetString(payload.FirstSpan)
        : GetStringSlow(payload, encoding);

    static string GetStringSlow(in ReadOnlySequence<byte> payload, Encoding encoding)
    {
        // linearize
        int length = checked((int)payload.Length);
        var oversized = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(length);
        try
        {
            payload.CopyTo(oversized);
            return encoding.GetString(oversized, 0, length);
        }
        finally
        {
            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(oversized);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `payload.Length` is > 2 GB? Also, its useful to note that this will be _amortized_ allocation free, and only for `payload.Length` < 2 MB. Beyond that, the `ArrayPool` (at least the current implementation), allocates an array anyway.

Comment: @ahsonkhan if the payload is over 2GiB then the string you need to create is likely over 4GiB (hard to know exact length, because of multi-byte UTF8 vs UTF16 with surrogate pairs, etc). So... Good luck with that! As for over the array pool size: "option 2"

Answer (score 0):

*Warning: **Not tested***

I made an improvement on the official answer:

- Packaged as an extension method
- Eliminates the need for a `StringBuilder`, by allocating an overestimate of the character array upfront
- Eliminates the need for the extra `GetCharCount` step, by using the single large array, summing the total characters found by `GetChars`, and shifting the target span slice
- Renaming a few variables. `preProcessedBytes` was particularly important to me, IMO they are not processed until after characters are derived.
- Using a stringLengthEstimate parameter so this can be used with protocols where the string length (in terms of character count) has been stored as a header before the UTF8 bytes

Here is the source code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parses UTF8 characters in the ReadOnlySequence
/// </summary>
/// <param name="slice">Aligned slice of ReadOnlySequence that contains the UTF8 string bytes. Use slice before calling this function to ensure you have an aligned slice.</param>
/// <param name="stringLengthEstimate">The amount of characters in the final string. You should use a header before the string bytes for the best accuracy. If you are not sure -1 means that the most pessimistic estimate will be used: slice.Length</param>
/// <returns>a string parsed from the bytes in the ReadOnlySequence</returns>
public static string ParseAsUTF8String(this ReadOnlySequence<byte> slice, int stringLengthEstimate = -1)
{
    if (stringLengthEstimate == -1)
        stringLengthEstimate = (int)slice.Length; //overestimate
    var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
    var preProcessedBytes = 0;
    var processedCharacters = 0;
    Span<char> characterSpan = stackalloc char[stringLengthEstimate]; 
    foreach (var memory in slice)
    {
        preProcessedBytes += memory.Length;
        var isLast = (preProcessedBytes == slice.Length);
        var emptyCharSlice = characterSpan.Slice(processedCharacters, characterSpan.Length - processedCharacters);
        var charCount = decoder.GetChars(memory.Span, emptyCharSlice, isLast);
        processedCharacters += charCount;
    }
    var finalCharacters = characterSpan.Slice(0, processedCharacters);
    return new string(finalCharacters);
}
```

Comment: stackalloc of a potentially unbounded size is frankly a terrible idea

Comment: @marcgravell Agreed. There could be a maximum bounds check and fallback to a heapbased character array